# TeamCity: How to reference a folder containing dll

Tags: teamcity

I have two VCS. 
VCS root: Application
VCS root: Library. Contains libraries used by Application
Both are in version control.

In Build step, what do I choose for Runner type?

Answer (score 0):

Any. Build steps and VCS roots is not dependent. With VCS root you specify how to retrieve sources and how to layout them in working directory. With Build steps wou specify what to do (compile) with retrieved sources and artifacts